# PHP: Instantiating a class from a variable oddly fails

Tags: php, laravel, instantiation, eloquent, laravel-3

I'm trying to instantiate a class (a Laravel3 Eloquent model) by a variable, and I'm getting an error saying that the class is not found.
When I hardcode the class name, though, it works just fine.
(FYI, in the code below `$contact_type` is expected to either be Phone, Fax, or Email.)

Here's what I'm playing with at the moment:

```
    foreach( $input AS $contact_type => $contact_info )
    {
        foreach( $contact_info AS $data )
        {
            $obj = new $contact_type( (array)$data);
            echo'<pre>Obj: ',print_r($obj),'</pre>';  // <----- For Testing
        }
    }
```

When I run the code as above, it throws a ***"Class 'Phone' not found"*** error.
When I replace `new $contact_type()` with `new Phone()` (or Fax or Email), it works just fine.
I bet there's something simple I'm just looking over :)  What am I missing?
Please help!

Comment: Are you in a namespace by any chance?

Comment: @deceze - Beat me to it. I bet that's it. Can't possibly think of anything else.

Comment: How's namespace related here? `$obj = new Phone()` should not work either if namespace are related

Comment: @RoyalBg Actually when you have aliased the namespace or class in a USE statement, it would work when written manually, but not work as a variable.

Comment: It's something new to me. Thanks. But why, where would be the difference?

Comment: @Jessica - Not just when `use`ing. Classes in the current namespace aren't resolved when using a string either.

Comment: @JosephSilber, I've not found that to be true, I have code that uses a variable for the name, and as long as it's in the same namespace and not aliased, it works just fine.

Comment: Are they resolved if you build the namespace with string? Sorry for asking without testing. Will test a bit later. And I still wonder why they are not resolved using a string, when in namespace

Comment: @Jessica - http://codepad.viper-7.com/38iklS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant manual entries that covers this are [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).  To quote the second link:

> If a string containing the name of a class is used with new, a new instance of that class will be created. If the class is in a namespace, its fully qualified name must be used when doing this.

This works for me:

```
class Phone {}
$classtype = 'Phone';
$phone = new $classtype();
var_dump($phone);
```

Produces the output:

```
object(Phone)#1 (0) {
}
```

Look to make sure you're not in a namespace (include the Phone class' namespace in the string if you are). Or, you can also try using reflection:

```
class Phone {}
$classtype = 'Phone';
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($classtype);
$phone = $reflectionClass->newInstanceArgs();
var_dump($phone);
```

If the Phone class is in a namespace, this also works:

**Phone.php**

```
<?php namespace Contact;

class Phone {}
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

include 'Phone.php';

$classtype = 'Contact\Phone';
$phone = new $classtype();
var_dump($phone);
```

I'm not 100% sure why, although I suspect that when evaluating a variable class name the current namespace mappings aren't visible.  Consider this code:

```
<?php namespace Foo;

use SomePackage\SomeClass as WeirdName;

$test = new WeirdName();
```

Compare that with:

```
<?php namespace Foo;

use SomePackage\SomeClass as WeirdName;

$class = 'WeirdName';
$test = new $class();
```

When PHP decides to allocate memory for a new instance, how will it know to map the class name alias of `WeirdName` to `SomePackage\Someclass`? That alias is only valid for the current file, and the code that actually performs that operation isn't even in [userland](http://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.php) code, much less the same file.

Comment: The issue was namespacing.  I have `use Person\Model\Eloquent\Phone` at the top of my script (which is why it works when I call for a `new Phone()`), but for some reason, when instantiating like `new $var()` I have to define the full namespace in variable ... If anyone can explain why, I'm **VERY** interested in learning.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why, but I updated my answer with what I suspect is the cause

Comment: Tnx, I fixed it too by defining the namespace in the variable.. which is not such a bad thing when dealing with several classes (not having to use them all separately). Although, when using a dynamic classname with Route::model(), this can bug your php artisan route:list command. Because it can't find the class empty string :p