# PHP dynamic class name laravel

Tags: php, class, laravel, dynamic

I am using Laravel and having trouble creating a class with a string. The class is in the same name space of the class calling it.

The below code fails on the third line, I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

```
$class= "Variant";
$s = new Variant();
$nc = new $class();
```

Comment: Try adding the full namespace to the string class and see if it works like: "\\Foo\\Bar\\Variant".

Comment: Fails = what error are you getting?

Comment: @rainer I had tried several different combinations, but this works (SplitTest) is my namespace of the class $class = "\\SplitTest\\Variant"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1: Calling a function from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789209/laravel-5-1-calling-a-function-from-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Instantiating a class from a variable oddly fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908496/php-instantiating-a-class-from-a-variable-oddly-fails)

Answer (score 3):

Ok the answer to this is I needed a namespace on the class.

In composer.json

```
"psr-4": {
    "SplitTest\\": "app/library/SplitTest/"
}
```

Then called the class as so:

```
$class= "//SplitTest//Variant";
$s = new Variant();
$nc = new $class();
```

If you to the psr-4 definition you will need to run

```
php artisan dump-auto
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually what namespaces are for:

`$s = new \OneNamespaceName\Variant();`

This is often used in a Factory pattern. So namespaces are per-file so you need to include this in the the class declaration for Variant.